# perl Undefined subroutine &Net::SNMPTrapd::pack_sockaddr_in

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use the sample script included with Net::SNMPTrapd, but it is failing on a Socket routine.
My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SNMPTrapd;

my $snmptrapd = Net::SNMPTrapd->new()
  or die "Error creating SNMPTrapd listener: ", Net::SNMPTrapd->error;

while (1) { 
    my $trap = $snmptrapd->get_trap();

    if ( !defined($trap) ) {
        printf "$0: %s\n", Net::SNMPTrapd->error;
        exit 1 
    } elsif ( $trap == 0 ) {
        next
    } 

    if ( !defined( $trap->process_trap() ) ) {
        printf "$0: %s\n", Net::SNMPTrapd->error
    } else { 
        printf "%s\t%i\t%i\t%s\n",
          $trap->remoteaddr,
          $trap->remoteport,
          $trap->version,
          $trap->community
    } 
}
```

When I run this and send a v2 trap to it from my Cisco router, it just dumps:

```
Undefined subroutine &Net::SNMPTrapd::pack_sockaddr_in called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Net/SNMPTrapd.pm line 554.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Socket qw(inet_ntoa AF_INET IPPROTO_TCP);
```

should be

```
use Socket qw(inet_ntoa AF_INET IPPROTO_TCP pack_sockaddr_in);
```

### Workaround

Change

```
use Net::SNMPTrapd;
```

to

```
use Net::SNMPTrapd;
BEGIN {
   *Net::SNMPTrapd::pack_sockaddr_in = \&Socket::pack_sockaddr_in
      if !defined(&Net::SNMPTrapd::pack_sockaddr_in);
}
```

This won't break even if the the module's author gets this fixed (after you [mention](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Report.html?Queue=Net-SNMPTrapd) it to him...)